# Codeception for WordPress: Command init not defined

Tags: wordpress, codeception

I followed the steps here (http://codeception.com/for/wordpress) and successfully installed Codeception. But when I enter `codecept init wpbrowser` into the terminal to get started with Codeception for Wordpress, I get the error: `Command init not defined`. How can I correct this?

Comment: Have you got the latest version of Codeception? Init command is only available in Codeception 2.3

Answer (score 1):

That's the correct command, but unfortunately, even the init command won't set everything up. It's very difficult to get CodeCeption to run the first time. At WordPress-BDD.com, we have a project going to get a WP dev server going with CodeCeption via one command. This will get WordPress CodeCeption going on a clean Ubuntu machine):

[Setup WordPress CodeCeption in the cloud](https://wordpress-bdd.com/bdd-wp-aws/)